# React select is not updating for default value

Tags: reactjs

I have a view that can be called both for creating new entry and updating an existing one.

When Im creating a brend new post, eveything works as expected.
When editing an existing post, the select box for regions is filled AND the current region is selected.
However, for the cities, the select box contains all the cities that belong to the region. But at the same time, the current city is not selected.
Both in the console and in the html-span I can see that the id is correct. But inside the option nothing happens.

***EDIT***

Full code that works for testing.

In package.json:

```
...
"react": "18.0.0",
"react-dom": "18.0.0",
"react-router-dom": "6.3.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.0"
```

In App.js:

```
<Route path="test" element={<Test />} />
```

In Test.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

export const Test = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [city, setCity] = useState('');
    const [region, setRegion] = useState('');
    const [regions, setRegions] = useState([]);
    const [cities, setCities] = useState([]);
    const [fetchingCities, setFetchingCities] = useState(false);

    const getCities = async () => {
        return [
            {_id: 1, region: 'region1', cities: [{id: '6293609d86af877f09bb9bc1', name: 'city1'},{id: '6293609d86af877f09bb9bc2', name: 'city2'}]}
            ,{_id: 2, region: 'region2', cities: [{id: '6293609d86af877f09bb9bc3', name: 'city3'},{id: '6293609d86af877f09bb9bc4', name: 'city4'}]}
        ]
    }

    const getAllCities = async () => {
        const all = await getCities();
        setRegions(all);
        const form = {
            region: 1,
            city: '6293609d86af877f09bb9bc1',
            name: 'testname'
        };
        if(form){
            setName(form.name);
            const cts = all.filter(e => e._id === Number(form.region));
            if(cts && cts.length && cts[0].cities){
                setCities(cts[0].cities);
                setRegion(form.region);
                setCity(form.city);
                console.log('form.city',form.city);
            }
        }

    }


    const citySelected = (value) => {
        console.log("value",value);
        setCity(value);
    }

    const cityChanged = (value) => {
        console.log("cityChanged",value);
        const cts = regions.filter(e => e._id === Number(value));
        console.log("cts",cts);
        if(cts && cts.length && cts[0].cities){
            setCities(cts[0].cities);
            setRegion(value);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!fetchingCities){
            setFetchingCities(true);
            getAllCities();
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" defaultValue={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    {
                        regions && regions.length > 0 &&
                        <select defaultValue={region} onChange={e => cityChanged(e.target.value)}>
                            <option value="">
                                Select
                            </option>
                            {regions.map((region, index) => (
                                <option key={index} value={region._id}>
                                    {region.region}
                                </option>
                            ))}
                        </select>
                    }
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select defaultValue={city} onChange={e => citySelected(e.target.value)}>
                        <option value="">
                            Select
                        </option>
                        {cities && cities.length > 0 && cities.map((city, index) => (
                            <option key={index} value={city.id}>
                                {city.name}
                            </option>
                        ))}
                    </select>
                </div>


                <span>city:{city}</span>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: Please post a repoducable version of your code

Comment: I updated the question with full working code.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the solution is to add the "value" attribute:

```
<select onChange={e => citySelected(e.target.value)} value={city}>
```

Comment: this answer works for me, but why defaultValues is not working for this!?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `useEffect` which sets the value of `city` every time `cities` changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCity(cities[0]?.id)
  //setCity(undefined) or this if you don't want a city to be preselected. 
}, [cities])
```

You can also add a selected option to verify make sure the selected city is the one shown in the dropdown.

```
{cities && cities.length > 0 && (
  cities.map((cityOption: any, index: any) => (
    <option
      selected={cityOption.id === city}
      key={index}
      value={cityOption.id}
    >
      {cityOption.name}
    </option>
  ))
)}
```

Comment: The first suggestion doesn't make any difference. While the second one not only doesn't work but also gives the warning "Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>", unfortunately.